# Plotting multivalued surface in mayavi

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, mayavi

### mayavi

I have some data which is on a structured grid in the X and Y directions and is unstructured in the Z direction. This is in the form of a list of data points, e.g `[[x,y,z], [x2,y2,z2], ...]`.  There are 2 points corresponding to most x,y coordinates, and the data is double valued in the z dimension. I would like to plot this shape as an enclosed surface, and if possible remove one of the walls.

I have tried the advice here: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html#example-surface-from-irregular-data

When I try this only the bottom half of the plot is covered by the surface. I also get this message which I don' understand: `No handlers could be found for logger "mayavi.core.common"`. I would love to know why this is.

I have tried plotting the top and bottom surfaces separately, but this looks a bit ugly. Here is what that looks like: [image: two surfaces plotted independently]

### matplotlib

I have also tried to grid my data and follow the advice using the matplotlib demos. I can't post the link to this because I don't have the reputation, but if you google matplotlib plot3D demos it is in the first result.

I can't get this to produce anything reasonable. I think this is because I don't really understand how the sphere example on that web page could be adapted to work with data rather than a function.

### Question

- how can I adapt the code I have from the link I provided to produce a plot of an enclosed surface?
- or, how can I use matplotlib to make the enclosed surface?
- Or is there some other program/function I ought to be using for this kind of problem?

Comment: Does unstructured in Z implies there are Z coordinates for points other than defined by the X-Y grid? Can you supply the data you want to plot?

Comment: Your mayavi plot looks like there is some problem with the point ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the end I solved this problem by turning my data on its side and interpolating the z values to a grid. Then I used the x axis to plot the data with the surface function. I think it may have been a problem with the point ordering (data is ordered in stripes of points going along the shape in the x direction) but I haven't managed to check this yet.